# How to crate a card with circle image and some text with HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am beginner. I am practicing HTML and CSS. In a practice project the below card is given.
[image]

How can I create this type of card with only HTML and CSS?

Please help me.

Comment: Hi, lookup some stuff like border-radius and text-align and position in CSS, have a go at some code and if you still have a problem post your code so we can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can  use the following code.

```css
.card {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 6px;
    max-width: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.card_img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: -60px auto 0;
}
.card_img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.card_info {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
}
a:hover{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"> <!-- Here I create a New Div with class name card -->
    <div class="card_img"> <!-- Here I create a New Div for image with class name card_img -->
        <img src="https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-1100x628.jpg" alt="user-image">
    </div>
    <div class="card_info"> <!-- Here I create a New Div for user info with class name card_info -->
        <h2>USER NAME</h2>
        <a href="#!">loremIpsum.com</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.card {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 6px;
    max-width: 350px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
.card_img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 100%;
    margin: -60px auto 0;
}
.card_img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.card_info {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: green;
}
a:hover{
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"> <!-- Here I create a New Div with class name card -->
    <div class="card_img"> <!-- Here I create a New Div for image with class name card_img -->
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/16164481/pexels-photo-16164481/free-photo-of-close-up-of-sleeping-cat.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1" alt="user-image">
    </div>
    <div class="card_info"> <!-- Here I create a New Div for user info with class name card_info -->
        <h2>NAME</h2>
        <a href="#!">hello</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: user-image]

### USER NAME

loremIpsum.com

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).